# Include css styles sent by a backend into a component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to include css styles sent by a backend into my component template.

My server response looks like this:

```
serverResponse: {
   content: '<div class="myClass classX">hello world</div>',
   styles: '.myClass{color:red} .classX{...}  ....';
}
```

(I know it's not a good idea to get css styles from a backend, but unfortunately I can't change it ;-)

My component template looks like this:

```
<style>
   <!-- serverResponse.styles should be in here. But how? -->
</style>
<div [innerHTML]="serverResponse.content">
   <!-- Binding to innerHTML works! -->
</div>
```

I have already set encapsulation to "ViewEncapsulation.None" in my component to enable styling with the `<style>` element.

What I have already tried is something like this:

```
<style [textContent]="serverResponse.styles">
```

But binding to textContent does not work...

I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Maybe you should [load entry component](http://blog.rangle.io/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-2/) dynamicly?

Comment: Why doesn't `<style [innerHTML]="serverResponse.styles">` work? What errors do you get?

Comment: @MrLister The style element is just not created

Answer (score 1):

First you should update your class property with your style from server response.

Then bind your style class property using style binding with your template.

Comment: I do agree that this is a better approach, I would highly recommend this over trying to dynamically add CSS to the page styles.

Comment: What do you mean with "update your class property"? The styles I get from the backend could contain multiple classes... E.g. serverResponse.styles = ".myClass{...} .classX{...}"

Answer (score 0):

I hesitated a bit since I don't think appending individual css rules to the page is good practice, but I will attempt to answer the question.

```js
$(function() {

  function handleElementResponse( html, css ) {
    console.log( $("style") );
    
    $("style").append( css );
    $("#mydiv").append( html );
  };
  
  handleElementResponse(
    "<div class=\"myClass\">hello world</div>",
    ".myClass{color:red}"
    );
    handleElementResponse(
    "<div class=\"myClass2\">hello world 2</div>",
    ".myClass2{color:blue}"
    );
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mydiv">
     <span class="someClass">Hello</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My humble opinion is that instead you should either:

1. Add the styles to the element directly using the "style" attribute
2. If possible, define your styles beforehand and just apply the classes to the html elements.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok this might work... But I'm wondering if there is a more Angular2-specific solution.